# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code, can you please tell me what is causing the error when printing? The function compose is supposed to compute function composition.

```
def compose(lst):
    return acc(g, h, lst)
print(compose([lambda x:x**2,lambda y:2*y])(5))
def acc(f, v, lst):
    if len(lst)==0:
        return v
    if len(lst)==1:
        return f(v,lst[0])
    return f(lst[0], acc(f,v,lst[1:]))
def h(f):
     return f
def g(f1,f2):
     return f1(f2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a function `g` that actually calls `f2` with arguments:

```
def g(f1, f2):
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        return f1(f2(*args, **kwargs))
    return func

print(compose([lambda x: x**2, lambda y: 2*y])(5))
```

Output:

```
100
```

This is equivalent to:

```
>>> (lambda x: x**2)((lambda y: 2*y)(5))
100
```

Answer (score 1):

At the last line `f1(f2)`, the argument given to `f1` is `f2` (a lambda), not the int 5.

You need to do something like `lst[0](lst[1](x))`

Comment: But the error still appears when I print the following`print(compose([lambda x:x**2,lambda y:2*y]))`

Comment: It happens at that line because that's when the faulty code is actually executed. When we just look at `def g(f1, f2) : return f1(f2)`, f1 and f2 could be anything, so at that point there's no way to tell if that code going to fail. It is only when the function `g` is called with parameter values `f1 = lambda x: x**2` and `f2 = lambda y: 2*y` that the error occurs, because putting `f2` in `x` leads to running `(lambda y: 2*y) ** 2`, and that causes the error you see

Comment: Thank you all! This worked when I changed the last line in function `g` with `return lambda x:f1(f2(x))`